# What the nature of JsExceptions and how to deal with that?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

In our gwt project in production mode we are sending uncaught exceptions with their stack trace to server. But sometimes we receive a JsExceptions with no stack trace, just java.lang.JsException. What is that? What can I do to realize where the error occured? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This indicates that some plain JS error has occurred that GWT can't translate in a meaningful way ("null pointer" in recent GWT is correctly wrapped, or through some other api that gets rewrapped as a `JavaScriptException`). Debugging this generally should proceed like any other JS exception - use the browser's debug tools to examine what happened and why.

Some less common ways to run into cases like this can include misbehaving other JS scripts on the page, potentially changing/replacing browser APIs, or the user installing other extensions which alter how browser APIs function.

Use the browser's debugger's "pause on caught and uncaught exceptions" feature to examine what happens in this case, or examine the stack trace in the JsException's `backingJsObject` field, or in the `getStackTrace()` return value. If it isn't present, this could mean that the browser is too old to capture one (and the emulated stack trace or legacy stack trace features are disabled in GWT), or that the underlying JS object simply doesn't have a stack trace for some reason.